# При нажатии на один из элементов меню обновлять часть страницы

Tags: jquery, ajax, html

Как при нажатии на один из элементов меню обновлялось только часть страницы, например, блок div?
Понимаю, что тут надо использовать ajax, но как именно, не знаю. Подскажите, как реализовать коротко и ясно, или посоветуйте какой-нибудь онлайн-ресурс, где все это описано.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) используйте [jQuery(javascript библиотека)](http://jquery.com), во много раз сэкономите время.

2) Про Ajax например [здесь](http://anton.shevchuk.name/wp-demo/jquery-tutorials-3/) можно прочитать

Мой пример вам:
Допустим есть php страница index.php, в нем блок с идентификатором ajax:

```
  index.php
<button id="getajax">Get Ajax</button>
<div id="ajax">/*Вот здесь будет ответ от request.php при нажатий кнопку getajax*/</div>
```

Нам нужно получить сообщение от request.php и засунут ответа в этот див :

```
request.php
<?if($_POST['do']=="yes"):?>
<? echo "Ответ от request";?>
<?endif;?>
```

Для этого пишем вот такую функцию в теле страницы index.php:

```
<script>
$('#getajax').live('click',function(){
    $.ajax({
`        `type:"POST",
          data:'do=yes',
          url:"request.php",
          success:function(in){  $('#ajax').html(in);   }

          });
})
</script>
```

Comment: @Vfvtnjd вы русский?

>страница index.php, в нем блок

надо писать: "в ней"

>и засунут ответа

надо писать: "и засунуть ответ"

Answer (score 2):

[@Vfvtnjd](/users/4996/vfvtnjd) y меня есть немного более изящный вариант скрипта ;)

```
$('button#getajax').click(function() {
   $('div#ajax').load('request.php');
});
```

По поводу PHP части, есть верный способ, как отличить AJAX запрос от обычного

```
if ( !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest' )
{
       # AJAX запрос. jQuery изменил заголовки запроса для нашего удобства 
}
```

[@Rules](/users/1267/rules) странно ... нормальные коменты могу минуснуть, а твой нет :)